# Get price where vertical line of crosshair and line is interseting

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I have a chart with lines and I want to get the price of every line, in the point where the vertical line of crosshair is intersecting them.

*Red circles are the prices for which I am looking for.*

[image]

This is the crosshair movement:

```
chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(param => {

  console.log(param.seriesData.get(buyLineSeries));

});
```

For now I use `param.seriesData.get(...)`, but this is returning the value only if in the intersection point, is also a point in lineSeries data.

How I can get the prices from any position of the line?